# Error ORA-02270

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm very new to SQL and I've been stuck on this for a while.

Three out of my four tables have been created, but the last one keeps coming up with the 'no matching unique or primary key for this column' error. I have absolutely no clue how to fix this.

Below are the two tables that are causing the problem, the error comes up when I try to create the sessions table.

```
CREATE TABLE SCREEN(
BRANCHID CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
SCREENID CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
SCREENCAPACITY CHAR(4),
CONSTRAINT SCREEN_PK PRIMARY KEY(SCREENID, BRANCHID),
CONSTRAINT SCREEN_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BRANCHID) REFERENCES BRANCH(BRANCHID));

CREATE TABLE SESSIONS(
SESSIONID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
BRANCHID CHAR(2),
SCREENID CHAR(2),
MOVIEID CHAR(2),
SESSIONDATE DATE,
SESSIONPRICE NUMBER(4,2),
CONSTRAINT SESSIONS_PK PRIMARY KEY(SESSIONID),
CONSTRAINT SESSIONS_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BRANCHID) REFERENCES BRANCH(BRANCHID),
CONSTRAINT SESSIONS_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(SCREENID) REFERENCES SCREEN(SCREENID),
CONSTRAINT SESSIONS_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(MOVIEID) REFERENCES MOVIE(MOVIEID));
```

This is starting to get really frustrating so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key `SESSIONS_FK2` is wrong.

The parent table `SCREEN` has `composite Primary key` so when you are referring it you need to add the composite columns in references

```
CONSTRAINT SESSIONS_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(SCREENID,BRANCHID) REFERENCES SCREEN(SCREENID,BRANCHID)
```

Also writing this answer based on `SQL SERVER` knowledge please comment if it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have a composite primary key for `screen`, so you have to refer to it using both components:

```
CONSTRAINT SESSIONS_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(SCREENID, BRANCHID) REFERENCES SCREEN(SCREENID, BRANCHID)
```